# How to deploy Shiny on web?

Tags: r, web, shiny

I want to deploy my Shinny app on the web, and I want to include it as part of a website I have developed on Wix. From what I understand, I must use a Self-hosted Shiny Server, right? In that case, do I must to use a Linux? Can't I use Windows or IOS?

Comment: [This](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/server/) is the place to go for all things Shiny Server-related (well, at least basic answers to broad questions like this). As it says, Windows and MacOS are not supported, but you could always run Ubuntu in a VM on those platforms. You can also deploy on [ShinyApps](http://www.shinyapps.io/signup.html), but I would not suggest hosting apps with proprietary or sensitive information there. I highly doubt there will be an iOS version of Shiny server. You can also deploy them as a package folks can run from within RStudio if central hosting is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Hosting the Shiny Server yourself requires Linux.

> Note: Shiny Server and Shiny Server Professional are currently only
>   supported on Linux.
>
> (http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/server/)

Soon, RStudio will offer fee-for-service hosting with [ShinyApps](http://shinyapps.io/). It's in alpha testing right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also host it through Shinyapps.io (http://www.shinyapps.io/).  Any application that you make online will be USERNAME.shinyapps.io, at least in the free version.